# не работает функция app.run() в pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

```
import time
import validation
import os
import logging
import requests
import download
from asyncio import sleep
import random
from background import keep_alive
import pyrogram
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.types import Message
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait
import asyncio
from pyrogram import errors, enums, Client, filters, types, raw
from gtts import gTTS
from nickname_generator import generate
from pytube import YouTube
from utils import *
import qrcode


api_id = "18971953"
api_hash = "39c218ce044e63128970764be7f24efe"

app = Client(name="user_bot", api_hash=api_hash, api_id=api_id, plugins=dict(root="mods"), device_model="USER-BOTIK")

@app.on_message(filters.command('ukrb', prefixes='.') & filters.all)
async def ukrbimb(_, msg):
  await msg.delete()
  await app.send_sticker(msg.chat.id, ("CAACAgIAAxkBAAEH9xBkAAGS0l_hAbw57k6p5xN8vvZp-6AAAlIYAAKx0QFIvahMhUrv8OkuBA"))

app.run()
```

ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/main.py", line 40, in 
> app.run()
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py", line 84, in run
> self.start()
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
> return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
> File "/nix/store/xf54733x4chbawkh1qvy9i1i4mlscy1c-python3-3.10.11/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
> return future.result()
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py", line 58, in start
> is_authorized = await self.connect()
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/auth/connect.py", line 40, in connect
> await self.load_session()
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 637, in load_session
> await Auth(
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/auth.py", line 274, in create
> raise e
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/auth.py", line 89, in create
> res_pq = await self.invoke(raw.functions.ReqPqMulti(nonce=nonce))
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/auth.py", line 67, in invoke
> return self.unpack(response)
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/auth.py", line 60, in unpack
> return TLObject.read(b)
> File "/home/runner/sanfi-user-bot-fix/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/raw/core/tl_object.py", line 33, in read
> return cast(TLObject, objects[int.from_bytes(b.read(4), "little")]).read(b, *args)
> KeyError: 0